# how to use styling tags to achieve different styles with tags of same type?

Tags: html, css

i want to use the following to style just one unordered list i have instead of all of them. I have tried to assign each field to a class and use a class attribute within the html however i couldn't get it working.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  border-bottom: solid #008348;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #FFD700;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="mypage1.html">Partners</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><a class="" href="index1.html">Main Page</a></li>
  <li><a href="mypage2.html">Partners2</a></li>
</ul>
```

So i only want the first unordered list to have the style. How do i achieve this?

Comment: for styling to the first element of an unordered list, you can use [first-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp) on your CSS code or you can also use [nth-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `class` or `id` to target the specific elements. When you apply the class/id to the `ul` element, you have to target the child element always mentioned with the parent element. As I believe you have tried without using parent level element like below.

```
ul.newclass {
 list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  border-bottom: solid #008348;
}

li {
  float: left;
 }

li a {
 display: block;
 color: #000000;
 font-size: 15px;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #C0C0C0;
}

li a:hover {
 background-color: #FFD700;
}
```

The above code will target the `ul` element will target the class have `newclass`. But it will target all the li elements because you have not mentioned it parent. You have to target the child element with the specific parent element like below.

```
 ul.newclass {
 list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  border-bottom: solid #008348;
}

ul.newclass li {
  float: left;
 }

ul.newclass li a {
 display: block;
 color: #000000;
 font-size: 15px;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #C0C0C0;
}

ul.newclass li a:hover {
 background-color: #FFD700;
}
```

Now all the `ul` and `li` element will apply based on the ul have the class `.newclass`. In my example I have used `ul.newclass`, which means it will target only the `ul` element have the class `.newclass`. Suppose if a `div` have a class `.newclass`, that will not affect.

```css
ul.newclass {
 list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  border-bottom: solid #008348;
}

ul.newclass li {
  float: left;
 }

ul.newclass li a {
 display: block;
 color: #000000;
 font-size: 15px;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #C0C0C0;
}

ul.newclass li a:hover {
 background-color: #FFD700;
}
```

```html
<ul class="newclass">
  <li><a class="" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="mypage1.html">Partners</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><a class="" href="index1.html">Main Page</a></li>
  <li><a href="mypage2.html">Partners2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of a class definition for the `ul` you want to style.

```css
ul.styled {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  border-bottom: solid #008348;
}

ul.styled li {
  float: left;
}

ul.styled li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}

ul.styled li a:hover {
  background-color: #FFD700;
}
```

```html
<ul class="styled">
  <li><a class="" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="mypage1.html">Partners</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><a class="" href="index1.html">Main Page</a></li>
  <li><a href="mypage2.html">Partners2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use :first-child attribute if you want only the first list item of every unordered list to have style. Try this.

```
ul li:first-child {
--your styles here--
}
```

However, if you want to style all the list item of first unordered list, you can use this.

```
ul:first-child li {
--your style here--
}
```